# Style Dynamic Table , TD fixed width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a **table** that create dynamically **tr** and **td**.

After a bunch of **td** created, they lost their formatting and result "compressed" each other.
How do i maintain constant width for each **td** created?

I tried to set **td**'s **width** attribute but after couple of insertions they compressed itself.

I need it because the **table** can grow up, so i need a scrolling bar to navigate. And to do that I want the **td** had fixed width

Comment: Have you set a fixed width value for the table or tr?

Comment: Without an html render, i won't be able to help you any further. (count the colspan, validate html, etc) But you can try  table style="table-layout:fixed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two things:

1. For your td's, just set the min-width. It will assure you a good width because the "normal" width attribute will still shrink if there is not enough space.
2. For the scroll bar, use the overflow attribute.

   ```
   <style>
       td { min-width: 150px; }
       table { overflow: scroll; }
   </style>
   ```

For more information about the overflow attribute: [www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Answer (score 1):

The comment above from @Milche Patern holds the key: `table-layout: fixed`.

I created a JSFiddle to illustrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/UxkUC/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <table id="my-fixed-width-table">
        <tr>
            <td> Cell 0 </td>
            <td> Cell 1 </td>
            <td> Cell 2 </td>
            <td> Cell 3 </td>
            <td> Cell 4 </td>
            <td> Cell 5 </td>
            <td> Cell 6 </td>
            <td> Cell 7 </td>
            <td> Cell 8 </td>
            <td> Cell 9 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Cell 0 </td>
            <td> Cell 1 </td>
            <td> Cell 2 </td>
            <td> Cell 3 </td>
            <td> Cell 4 </td>
            <td> Cell 5 </td>
            <td> Cell 6 </td>
            <td> Cell 7 </td>
            <td> Cell 8 </td>
            <td> Cell 9 </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#my-fixed-width-table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#my-fixed-width-table td {
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    text-align: center;
}
```